# Reject a record automatically

Tags: approval-process

Is it possible to reject a record automatically if it hasn't been approved after a few days say a week?

Ex: I have a record which is sent for approval a week ago and the manager hasn't approved it yet. So I want it to be rejected automatically? Is there anyway to do it? I searched for it but couldn't find anything so if anyone can help me out, I'd be grateful!

Comment: Ash has a pretty good answer, but what he didn't mention was to research how to build a batch class.. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like below:

- Create a Scheduler which runs after every week.
- Run batch class from Scheduler
- Query all `ProcessInstanceWorkitem` like below

`public Id getWorkItemId(Id targetObjectId){
    List<String> result = new List<String>();
    for(ProcessInstanceWorkitem record  : [Select Id FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem 
                                                WHERE ElapsedTimeInDays = 7 ])
    {
        result.add(record.Id);
    }
    return result;
}`

And then reject them like below:

`public void rejectRecord(){
    List<String> allRejectableRequestList = getWorkItemId(); 
    for(String record : allRejectableRequestList){
        Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
        req.setComments('Rejected request as manager is not approving from last 7 days');
        req.setAction('Reject');
        req.setWorkitemId(record);
        Approval.ProcessResult result =  Approval.process(req);
    }
}`

I hope this will help you